# HTML Border remove

Tags: html

Basic, but annoying. For the life of me I can't work out how to remove the white borders around the top and sides of the page…any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.rightBar {
    background-color: #596a87;
    overflow: auto
}

.leftBar {
    background-color: #54ff37;
    position: relative;
}

</style>
```

Is there something I need to do with the CSS?

```
</head>
```

Or the content of the body/divs?

```
<body>

<div id="main" style="position:static;">
<div class="leftBar" style="height:100%;width:50%;position:fixed"></div>

<div class="rightBar" style="padding:6px;height:100%;width:49.5%;position:relative;left:50%;" id="rightContent">
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
10<br />
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

I think most browsers add margin and padding to the websites.  If you don't want that you have to specify that in the css or on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking for, you should add something like this to your style:

```
:root, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

---

By the way, it might prove useful to add a reset sheet to your project such as the [normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) css reset sheet, that way you can be sure to have all the default values (such as margin and padding for regular tags) resetted and you can style them yourself more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

A more complicated solution would be to use a CSS RESET style sheet to remove all vendor-specific defaults. The 10 pixel margin described above is among them.

I believe Eric Meyer was one of the first to implement this, but now it is a common practice. There is a pro and con side, and not all of the selectors or properties will be necessary for any one site. Being CSS, it's easy enough to determine what fits your needs.

meyerweb: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/